# Pass Variable Within Methods In Same Activity

Tags: android

I would like to pass variable from method 1 into method 2, I tried using intent but this works for activities not methods. Please see code below:

METHOD 1:

```
public void sendFeedback(View button) { 

   final EditText nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextName);
   String name = nameField.getText().toString();
   System.out.println("Name is: " +  name);
}
```

METHOD 2:

```
private void diaglogue()
{       
    Some code…
{
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        System.out.println("Name is: " +  name);
     }
```

METHOD 1 will print as:
    Name is John

METHOD 2 will print as:
    Name is null

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What do you want to pass where? Also, [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)

Comment: save name as a member variable and it won't be null. name only appears to be defined in the scope of the sendFeedback method, so you need to make it available to method 2 either by including it in method 2's scope or passing it to method 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want any variable in your entire class you need to define it at the class level.

Do it as,

```
public Activity1 extends Activity{

String name;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedState){
    name = nameField.getText().toString();
    //your code...
}

method1(){
    System.out.println("Name is: " +  name);
}
method2(){
    System.out.println("Name is: " +  name);
}
```

Comment: This really isn't good advice. If the OP needs variables just in these two methods then passing them would be more appropriate

Comment: @ Apurva - Nope, name in second method is still null

Comment: @ Apurva - Got it now